# GCC -l option across specified in case of a high number of libraries

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries

Maybe i'm missing something but when i compile my program with shared libraries *.so i always have to use -llib for each and every library im using.

Now i've a project that links against 40 of them (possibly) and given that this "framework" of library is quite big it's not easy at all find out where each reference is.

Do i really have to know in which *.so file there is what im looking for or is there an automatic/faster way, like using -L for the full path and tell the compiler search in here?

"ldd" command might help in case i have a similar application that uses same library but i still need to add them at least once in the gcc/makefile.

Is this the only way or is there a faster/simpler way? I understand that i might have 2 *.so file with the same function name but at that point i would be happy to receive a "redefined" error.

Moreover how do i find out what a *.so or *.dll (even *.a static lib) file are containing in terms of possible usable references?

Thanks,

Comment: The `Is this the only way or is there a faster/simpler way?` and `Moreover how do i find out what` seems like separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Do i really have to know in which *.so

Yes.

> Is this the only way

Well, no, you can write your own solution yourself.

> or is there a faster/simpler way?

I do not believe so, even if there is, I do not believe it would be practical to use it.

> how do i find out what a

Example:

```
$ gcc /tmp/1.c 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc2lZAPF.o: in function `main':
1.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
```

Och no! Once again we forgot to link with `-pthread`. But fear no more, just for the fun of it, I created the following `,ld_find_symbol` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT AND Beerware

name=$(basename "$0")

usage() {
    cat <<EOF
Usage: $name <symbol>...

Options:
  -d <database>
  -h

Finds the symbol in libraries.

Written by Kamil Cukrowski
Licensed jointly under Beerware License and MIT License.
EOF
}

args=$(getopt -n "$name" -o d:h -- "$@")
eval set -- "$args"
database=/tmp/database.txt
while (($#)); do
    case "$1" in
    -d) database=$2; shift; ;;
    -h) usage; exit; ;;
    --) shift; break; ;;
    esac
    shift
done
if ((!$#)); then usage; exit 1; fi;

if [[ -e "$database" ]]; then
    echo "Using $database"
else
    echo "Creating $database"

    # list all ld search paths
    ld --verbose | grep SEARCH_DIR | tr -s ' ;' '\n' |
    # In a format something we can eat
    sed 's/SEARCH_DIR("\(.*\)")/\1/' |
    # Resolve symlinks, remove duplicates
    # Remove non-existent directories
    xargs -d'\n' -n1 sh -c '
        set -- "$(readlink -f "$1")"
        if [ -e "$1" ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$1"
        fi
        :
    ' _ |
    sort -u |
    # List all .so and .a files from that dir
    # Calling `file` would be very slow
    xargs -d'\n' -I{} find {} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f \
        '(' -name 'lib*.so.*' -o -name 'lib*.a' ')' |
    # list filename and symbol in each library
    (
        # we list all symbols listed in any elf section
        list_symbols() {
            readelf -Ws "$1" |
            sed '/^ *[^ ]*: *[^ ]* *[^ ]* *[^ ]* *[^ ]* *[^ ]* * [0-9]\{1,\} *\([^ ]\{1,\}\)$/!d; s``\1\t'"$1"'`' ||: |
            sort -u
            # log the filename that we are ready
            echo "Indexed: $1" >&3
        }
        export -f list_symbols
        # extra stdbuf -oL so that buffering can't touch this
        # I guess we should be safe till _POSIX_PIPE_BUF
        stdbuf -oL xargs -P$(nproc) -n1 \
            stdbuf -oL bash -c 'list_symbols "$@"' _ 
    ) |
    # sort it
    sort -t $'\t' -u -o "$database"

fi 3>&1

for i in "$@"; do
    look -t $'\t' "$i" "$database" |
    grep -F "$i"$'\t'
done
```

So we can run:

```
$ ,ld_find_symbol pthread_create
...
pthread_create  /usr/lib/libasan.so.5.0.0
pthread_create  /usr/lib/liblsan.so.0.0.0
pthread_create  /usr/lib/libpthread.a
pthread_create  /usr/lib/libtsan.so.0.0.0
```

Och symbol found. So now we can:

```
$ gcc /tmp/1.c -l:libpthread.a
... errors ....
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x202e): undefined reference to `_dl_stack_flags
```

So we can once again:

```
$ ,ld_find_symbol _dl_pagesize
/usr/lib/libc.a
```

And fix it with:

```
$ gcc /tmp/1.c -l:libpthread.a -l:libc.a
```

Maybe with some work this could be scripted to work auto-magically and auto-detect the missing symbols. Still, it's a lot of work for that left.